# SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500 error using Selenium Java and WebDriverManager through pom.xml

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I want to test my script on chrome beta version and for that reason I have installed chrome beta version but somehow I am not able to start it using Selenium Java. I have all the needed dependency added in `pom.xml` file regarding webdriver manager etc. I am sharing my console error and also script.

```
ChromeOptions optionsBeta = new ChromeOptions();
optionsBeta.setBinary("C:\\Users\\WRP\\Downloads\\Programs\\ChromeSetup.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\WRP\\eclipse-workspace\\PracticeProject\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(optionsBeta);
//System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Driver/chromedriver.exe");
//  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
//WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("104.0.5112.29").setup();
//WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait waits=new WebDriverWait (driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Error tracelogs:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 104.0.5112.29 (eff877e18f767c77fef0481a1cba402c8cbad404-refs/branch-heads/5112@{#422}) on port 55215
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Users\WRP\Downloads\Programs\ChromeSetup.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'AWAIS-PC', ip: '192.168.1.62', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], binary: C:\Users\WRP\Downloads\Prog..., extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], binary: C:\Users\WRP\Downloads\Prog..., extensions: []}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:264)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:70)
    at First_Test.Practice_First.main(Practice_First.java:29)
```

Comment: Change the binary path to existing chrome.exe file, instead of Chrome**Setup**.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Users\WRP\Downloads\Programs\ChromeSetup.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your have to take care of a couple of things here as follows:

- `setBinary()` argument should be used to point to the binary executable i.e. *`chrome.exe`* post installation of the browser software (*`ChromeSetup.exe`*)

  ```
  optionsBeta.setBinary("C:\\location\\to\\chrome.exe");
  ```
- You'd use ***either*** of the following (*not both*):

  - The downloaded version of the **chromedriver.exe** using the `System.setProperty()` line as follows:

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\WRP\\eclipse-workspace\\PracticeProject\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    ```
  - The ***WebDriverManager*** dependency in `pom.xml` and setup the chromedriver as:

    ```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ```

Your effective code block will be:

- Using downloaded [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447):

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\WRP\\eclipse-workspace\\PracticeProject\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions optionsBeta = new ChromeOptions();
  optionsBeta.setBinary("C:\\location\\to\\chrome.exe");      
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(optionsBeta);
  ```
- Using *Maven Dependency* in `pom.xml`:

  ```
  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("104.0.5112.29").setup();
  ChromeOptions optionsBeta = new ChromeOptions();
  optionsBeta.setBinary("C:\\location\\to\\chrome.exe");      
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(optionsBeta);
  ```

Comment: thanx alot for the valuable feed back , it really worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Use the below chrome option

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
```

This line very important on skip this error

```
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use headless mode and disable the GUI mode. And specify the chrome binary path in Chromeoption class inside the selenium codes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).