# Why edgedriver is crashed while chromedriver / firefoxdriver are working fine?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-edgedriver, selenium-java

Why edgedriver is crashed while chromedriver / firefoxdriver are working fine?

Here are the error message

```
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://aka.ms/WebDriverSecurity for suggestions on keeping Microsoft Edge WebDriver safe.

Microsoft Edge WebDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Microsoft Edge failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from msedge location /Applications/Microsoft Edge.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Edge is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.4.0', revision: 'e5c75ed026a'
System info: host: 'Alans-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1c1d:b4b6:77a2:3994%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '12.3', java.version: '19.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage], extensions: []}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:46)
    at testingdriver.main(testingdriver.java:29)
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
\<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java --\>
\<dependency\>
\<groupId\>org.seleniumhq.selenium\</groupId\>
\<artifactId\>selenium-java\</artifactId\>
\<version\>4.4.0\</version\>
\</dependency\>

\<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager --\>
\<dependency\>
\<groupId\>io.github.bonigarcia\</groupId\>
\<artifactId\>webdrivermanager\</artifactId\>
\<version\>5.3.1\</version\>
\</dependency\>
```

and here is my code

```
WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();

        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();

        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);

        driver.get("https://google.com");
        System.out.println("success");
        driver.quit();
```

I have tried almost every method that shared in the web. However, I dont manage to see any possible reason this is happening.

I tried with downloading edgedriver from the official microsoft web and declare the path in the
`System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","//Users/alanliew/Desktop/Automation/Selenium-Java/CGWeb/untitled2/msedgedriver");`

but the same error happen.

Anyone able to find solution to this ?

Comment: I have tried with chromedriver and firefoxdriver , however issue seem to happen only in edgedriver

Comment: Hope this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73021320/sessionnotcreatedexception-could-not-start-a-new-session-response-code-500-err

Comment: thanks manish, however, I have tried with options.setBinary("/path/msedgedriver") too but things are not working out

Comment: Did you try with latest Selenium version? 4.10.0